# Building VM with packer hangs on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, virtualbox, packer

I downloaded packer and packer-windows (https://github.com/joefitzgerald/packer-windows)
and simply started `packer build -only=virtualbox-iso windows_81.json`.
I get the following output

```
==> virtualbox-iso: Downloading or copying Guest additions
virtualbox-iso: Downloading or copying:   file:///Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
==> virtualbox-iso: Downloading or copying ISO
virtualbox-iso: Downloading or copying: http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/9/9/B999286E-0A47-406D-8B3D-5B5AD7373A4A/9600.16384.WINBLUE_RTM.130821-1623_X64FRE_ENTERPRISE_EVAL_EN-US-IRM_CENA_X64FREE_EN-US_DV5.ISO
==> virtualbox-iso: Creating floppy disk...
virtualbox-iso: Copying: ./answer_files/81/Autounattend.xml
virtualbox-iso: Copying: ./scripts/microsoft-updates.bat
virtualbox-iso: Copying: ./scripts/win-updates.ps1
virtualbox-iso: Copying: ./scripts/openssh.ps1
virtualbox-iso: Copying: ./scripts/oracle-cert.cer
==> virtualbox-iso: Creating virtual machine...
==> virtualbox-iso: Creating hard drive...
==> virtualbox-iso: Attaching floppy disk...
==> virtualbox-iso: Creating forwarded port mapping for SSH (host port 3422)
==> virtualbox-iso: Executing custom VBoxManage commands...
virtualbox-iso: Executing: modifyvm packer-virtualbox-iso-1441806753 --memory 2048
virtualbox-iso: Executing: modifyvm packer-virtualbox-iso-1441806753 --cpus 2
==> virtualbox-iso: Starting the virtual machine...
virtualbox-iso: WARNING: The VM will be started in headless mode, as configured.
virtualbox-iso: In headless mode, errors during the boot sequence or OS setup
virtualbox-iso: won't be easily visible. Use at your own discretion.
==> virtualbox-iso: Waiting 2m0s for boot...
==> virtualbox-iso: Typing the boot command...
==> virtualbox-iso: Waiting for SSH to become available...
```

At this point it hangs and nothing happens.

Looking at VirtualBox what is going on, I can see that the installation of Win8 is at the first screen (at which one must enter Language settings, time and currency format etc).

Also I expected that all the unattended stuff is happening before. I checked that the openssh script is available - and I assume that the default configuration from packer-windows does not need any more edits to function.

So what is missing ? Should I see the output from all the scripts in the output ?

Comment: you can add `-debug` option to see more output and whats going on and where it hangs. read https://www.packer.io/docs/command-line/build.html#_debug for information about this option

Comment: unfortunately this gives not more information, only stops after each step and waits for user action to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the tips from https://github.com/joefitzgerald/packer-windows/issues/159, it might be you run into the same situation that the update download takes a lot of time.

You can:

- extend the `ssh_wait_timeout` in the packer template
- set `MaxUpdatesPerCycle` to 30 (see https://github.com/joefitzgerald/packer-windows/pull/135)

It did the trick for me, after I made those modifications, I can pass

```
==> virtualbox-iso: Waiting for SSH to become available...
==> virtualbox-iso: Connected to SSH!
==> virtualbox-iso: Uploading VirtualBox version info (4.3.16)
==> virtualbox-iso: Uploading VirtualBox guest additions ISO...
==> virtualbox-iso: Provisioning with shell script: ./scripts/vm-guest-tools.bat
```

Thanks! I needed to test windows from vagrant :) that kind of force me

Comment: thanks i will try this over the weekend. I also tried it with Win7 and there I so that it can take hours for the update etc, so it might be "simply" the update, with the problem of not seeing this in the Vm ui

Comment: unfortunately this did not helped. I checked your points and the MaxUpdatesPerCycle is already set to 30 and i set the ssh_wait_timeout to 24h, but it still got stuck on the first login screen

Comment: weird, for me it clearly helped ! I was not able to run it before and then with the change it did work. the MaxUpdatesPerCycle is not set from the original git (at least for windows 81) you need to change `answer_files/81/Autounattend.xml` line 260 (`<CommandLine>cmd.exe /c C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -File a:\win-updates.ps1 -MaxUpdatesPerCycle 30</CommandLine>`) also did you correctly change `ssh_wait_timeout` for your provider ? in windows_81.json, the 2 providers (virtual box and vmware) are defined

Comment: you damn, you are right, the MaxUpdatePerCycle is not in there - it is though in the answer_file for win 7.1. So this means I will try it again tonight.